# How to structure this context in terms of view files and routes?

Tags: laravel

The front end of the app has this left page where a user can create a new conference. This page is accessed with the url "http://proj.test/createConference".

After storing the conference the user should be redirected to the index page of the management area for that specific conference. The url could be something like "http://proj.test/myconference/2".

The user has also always access to a submenu with two links to list the conferences created by him and to edit his user account.

[image]

This management area is specific for each conference that a user created and in this area the user can edit the conference details (title, description, etc) but can also manage other aspects of the conference like edit registration types, list participants etc.

**Doubt**

My doubt is which method of the ConferneceControler use, how to register the routes and how to organize the files in the view folder for this context of redirect the user to the conference management area of a specific conference after he creates the conference. And also for the context when the user accesses the link "Manage Conference" on a specific conference (actually, they are both the same context).

**Structure that I have for now without the context of the user can access the conference management area for each conference that he creates:**

**Views directory:**

```
views
   createConference.blade.php (page with a form to create new conference) 
   app.blade.php (template shared by all frontend pages)
   index.blade.php (index page of the frontend)
```

**Routes:**

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function(){

    Route::post('/conference/store', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@store',
        'as'   => 'conference.store'
    ]);

    Route::get('/createConference', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@create',
        'as'   => 'conference.create'
    ]);
});
```

**ConferenceController store method:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
         ...
    ]);
    $conference = Conference::create([
        'name' => $request->conference_name,
        ...
    ]);
    // here the user should be redirected to the conference management area specific for this created conference
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below sketch of how I would structure it.

```
views // First option
    conference
        create.blade.php // left image
        manage.blade.php // bottom right
        list.blade.php // top right
    participants
        ...
    layout
        main.blade.php // template shared by all frontend pages

views // Second option
    conference
        create.blade.php // left image
        list.blade.php // top right
    manageConference
        index.blade.php // bottom right
    participants
        ...
    layout
        main.blade.php // template shared by all frontend pages


GET:    /conference                             -> @index
GET:    /conference/create                      -> @create
POST:   /conference                             -> @store
GET:    /conference/edit/<conference-tag>       -> @edit
POST:   /conference/update/<conference-tag>     -> @update

GET:    /conference/manage/<conference-tag>     -> @manage // First option
or
GET:    /manageConference/<conference-tag>      -> ManageConference@index // Second option


@store -> @manage
```

I'm not sure why would you pass `'as' => 'conference.create'` in your routes, but I might be lacking bigger picture.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the layout folder, you have the main.blade.php that is the template shared by all frontend pages. I have also a template to be shared by all conference management pages. This file should be placed also in this layout folder with a name, for example, conferencemanagement.blade.php?

Comment: Also with your structure after storing the conference where to redirect to user? Like below?

 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'conference_name' => 'required|max:255|string',
         ...
    ]);
    $conference = Conference::create([
        'name' => $request->conference_name,
        ...
    ]);
    return redirect()->route('conference.manage', ['id' => $conference->id]);
}

Comment: And then the route for this is like below?

Route::get('conference/mange/{id}', [
    'uses' => 'ConferenceController@manage',
]);
If this is correct, then this manage method what should have?

Comment: I have the "as' => 'conference.create'" in the routes  Route::get('/createConference', [
        'uses' => 'ConferenceController@create',
        'as'   => 'conference.create'
    ]); And then in the create method i have: public function create()
{
    return view('app.createConference')->with('categories', Category::all());
}.

Comment: layout/conferencemanagement.blade.php: Yes. It can also extend main layout. 
Redirect: Yes.

Comment: Manage method should have all the logic necessary to display the view. It is not responsible for storing anything.

Comment: In the `createConference` I would change the naming to `/conference/create` and make it render `/conference/create.blade.php`

Comment: Thanks really, just one more doubt: So after storing the conference the user should be redirected to: "return redirect()->route('conference.manage', ['id' => $conference->id]); }"? And the route for this should be like this: "Route::get('conference/mange/{id}', [ 'uses' => 'ConferenceController@manage', ]);"? And then the manage method what view should return? Im with a doubt in this.

Comment: Manage method should return the bottom right view in your picture ("IT Conference")

Comment: Thanks, but that "IT Conference" view is not already returned after storing the conference with "return redirect()->route('conference.manage', ['id' => $conference->id]); }"?

Comment: Yes it is, after storing the conference you go to `conference/manage` which renders the view. It does not redirect anywhere.
How I understand  your question: What view should `conference/manage` render? A: It should render the ("IT Conference") view.

Please clarify a bit more if its not what you are asking about. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! After storing the conference I have the redirect with "return redirect()->route('conference.manage', ['id' => $conference->id]);"so the user goes to "http://proj.test/conference/manage/6" because I have the route "Route::get('conference/manage/{id}', [ 'uses' => 'ConferenceController@manage', 'as'=>'conference.manage']);".

Comment: But it appears an error in this page: "Method [manage] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers/ConferenceController]." I'm not understanding how to fix this issue, I should create a new route or just a manage() method or both ? And which content it should have?

Comment: You should create `manage()` method in `ConferenceController`. It should contain rendering of ("IT Conferences").

Comment: I was not understanding because Im a beginner, but so in the store method the redirect "return redirect()->route('conference.manage', ['id' => $conference->id]);" is just to redirect the user to a specific route, in this case conference.manage but to render the view is necessary to create the manage method because is what the "confenrece.mange" route expects with the defined route: "Route::get('conference/manage/{id}', [ 'uses' => 'ConferenceController@manage', 'as'=>'conference.manage']);" . Right? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, you have to have a corresponding method in controller.